# Auto filling a filed from another separate field when a checkbox is checked

Tags: forms, input, label, legend, fieldset

function billingFunction (){   if(document.getElementById('same').checked){
document.getElementById('billingName').setAttribute('value') = document.getElementById('shippingName').value
document.getElementById('billingZip').setAttribute('value') = document.getElementById('shippingZip').value
}
}